# Kinect SDK 1.0 + Unity / Blender

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, blender

I'm trying to figure out how to pass datas from kinect sensor to unity 3d.
I've found this interesting project http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Unity-and-the-Kinect-SDK , but unfortunately it works only with the Beta release, and not with the recent version of the SDK (1.0).

Anybody could suggest me a way to do that? I could also use Blender if something else exists.

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446289/official-kinect-sdk-and-unity3d?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Check out [zigfu.com](http://zigfu.com) - Unity bindings for Kinect/OpenNI devices. Works with the new Kinect For Windows SDK, and also has webplayer support!

Comment: It looks great, thank you.
In their last blog post (18th February) they say
"Support for Microsoft Kinect SDK using Kinect for Windows", but they don't say if it fits also for the latest Kinect SDK 1.0 or just with the Beta.
Do you know if it works?

Comment: Too bad. I can't use proprietary software.